# Can a block cipher with fixed point permutations be a good PRP?

Tags: hash, pseudo-random-permutation

Let $E:\{0,1\}^n \times \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$ be a good PRP and consider blockcipher $\widetilde{E}$ defined as follows

$$\widetilde{E}(K,X) = \begin{cases}K & \text{if } X=K \\ E(K,K ) & \text{if } X = E^{-1}(K,K)\\ E(K,X) & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

[Black](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/210.ps) used this to show that [Matyas-Meyer-Oseas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Matyas%E2%80%93Meyer%E2%80%93Oseas) construction which is proven in the ideal-cipher-model can fail in the standard model, i.e. it will fail if we instantiate it with $\widetilde{E}$;

> So $\widetilde{E}$ is the same block cipher as $E$  with one change: we now have the invariant  that $E(K, K)= K$ for all $K \in \{0, 1\}^n$. Clearly   $\widetilde{E}$
>   is a good PRP since have $E$ was:  for a randomly chosen key $K, \widetilde{E}(K,\cdot)$
>  is computationally indistinguishable from a random permutation.

Is the claim *computationally indistinguishable from a random permutation* true?

We can say that for a fixed key $K$, $\widetilde{E}$ we will always output $K$ if $ K = X$

The probability of getting a single point is fixed from all permutations of $k$ elements is $\frac{(k-1)!}{k!} = \dfrac{1}{k}$.

If we turn this into permutations generated by the $n$-bit block cipher. Then we have $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$. Therefore the permutations of $\widetilde{E}$ is distinguishable and $\widetilde{E}$ cannot be a good PRP.

Any missing point?

Could one provide a formal proof for this an example?

Comment: How would an efficient adversary *detect* the fixed point?

Comment: Related [Are encryption algorithms with fixed-point free permutations inherently flawed?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/67465/18298)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer

As Maeher said, the adversary cannot recognize which points are reprogrammed or distinguish $\widetilde E$ from $E$, given oracle access to $\widetilde E$ (or $E$). This is because the adversary who detects such points can also be used to break the PRP security of $E$ by finding the key $K$.

#### Formal proof

It suffices to prove that no efficient algorithm can distinguish $E$ from $\widetilde E$ via oracle access. That is, we will prove that for any efficient $A$ with $q$ query to the oracle such that
$$
|\Pr_{K}[A^{E(K,\cdot)}()=1] - \Pr_K[A^{\widetilde E(K,\cdot)}() =1]|=\epsilon, \label{1}\tag{1}
$$
it holds that $\epsilon$ is negligibly small.

To measure the advantage in a different term, first note that a difference in the oracle access to $E$ and $\widetilde E$ only happens if the adversary query $(K,K)$ or $(K,X)$ for $X=E^{-1}(K,K)$ to the oracle. Otherwise, both oracles work exactly the same and there is no chance to figure out the difference. Let's say the above event by $\rm Bad$. Then it holds that
$$
\epsilon \le \Pr_K[A^{E(K,\cdot)}()=1|{\rm Bad}] \le \Pr_K[A^{E(K,\cdot)}()|{\rm Bad}].\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
Note that whether the oracle is $E$ or $\widetilde E$ doesn't make any difference. We choose $E$ here.

What is the probability of $\rm Bad$? We define a new adversary $B$ having oracle access to $E$ to find the key of PRP as follows.

1. Choose a random $1 \le i \le q$.
2. Run $A$ with the given oracle right before $i$-th query. Let the input of $i$-th query by $X$ and with probability, $1/2$ do either

   - output $X$, or
   - query $X$ to the oracle and output the answer $E(K,X)$.

Suppose that in the $i$-th query the $\rm Bad$ event occurs. If the first case of $\rm Bad$ occurs, i.e. $A$ queries $K$ to the oracle, then $B$ outputs $K$ with probability $\epsilon/2q$ by the first action (output $X$ directly).
On the other hand, if $A$ queries $E^{-1}(K,K)$, the second action outputs $E(K,E^{-1}(K,K))=K$ that also has probability $\epsilon/2q$.
Overall, the algorithm $B$ outputs $K$ with probability $\epsilon/2q$.

However, the PRP security of $E$ says that this probability is negligibly small. This implies $\epsilon$ is small as well since $q$ is polynomially bounded (given that $A$ is efficient). Thus no efficient algorithm can distinguish $E$ from $\widetilde E$ via oracle access, and since $E$ is PRP, $\widetilde E$ is a PRP as well, which is as we desired.

Comment: What fo you mean by $\Pr_K[A^{E(K,\cdot)}()|{\rm Bad}]$?

Comment: @kelalaka I intended the probability that the bad event occur while running $A$, regardless of its output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Consider this as a learning question for me.
I've read this $\Pr_K[A^{E(K,\cdot)}()|{\rm Bad}]$ like conditional probability.
Is it? Are there any relation between the two $\epsilon$ in the equations 1 and 2?
Why the probability is $\epsilon/2q$, doesn't the bad event occurs once?

Comment: @YunusKarakaya Sorry for my bad presentation. The probability $Pr_K[A^{E(K,⋅)}()|Bad]$ says the chance that $A$ met Bad event in its running. I used the term for showing the inequality. Two $\epsilon$'s are the same, and the argument between equation 1 and 2 shows inequality 2, which essentially says the advantage of adversary $\epsilon$ is less than the probability of Bad event.

Comment: For the last part, we constructed an adversary $B$ that finds the key of PRP whenever it halts the exact point that Bad event occurs. The bad event occurs probability at least $\epsilon$ by inequality 2, and the probability that the random guess of $B$ find the Bad point is (if any) $1/2q$. Combining them, $B$ finds the point that Bad event happens with probability $\epsilon/2q$, which is not negligible.